# SuiteCRM add custom where condition in view.popup.php?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

How to add custom where condition in view.popup.php ?

Someone suggests me to add custom where condition in view.list.php but my problem is, view.popup.php not calling the view.list.php so there is no meaning to add a custom condition in view.list.php.

Or is this possible to link custom view.popup.php to custom view.list.php ?

Comment: you should only ask once or you will be marked as duplicate.
I had answered you before, I had a downvote but don't know why, I have that functionality working with the process  I roughly outlined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SuiteCRM Make custom where condition query for popview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48963940/suitecrm-make-custom-where-condition-query-for-popview)

Comment: I never given downvote to anyone in the past, so why you want to give me ?

And also can you explain me how your answer will resolve my problem, if you really help me then i will give you positive vote, I think the purpose of stackoverflow is to resolve each others problems and not just to collect votes and make profile, think positive :)

Comment: Hi Sagar, I am sorry I left that impression that I only wanted your vote. First, I tried to help you giving you a detailed answer in another post, so if you don't understand that answer you should have commented there, not creating a new question.  
SO is to help each other solve, not to solve it, its quite a difference, and the difference is the effort you put in. If you check the the legend for the downvote arrow, you will read "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"  which in my opinion it is.

Comment: you want to change the listing of popup records and that should be filtered on the basis of certain conditions? I can give you code sample which can give you idea that how you can change listing queries but again if you are looking for some complete code according to your requirement  then you have to learn how to code before asking question as people here really expect that questioner know how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Following is long code because most of the code is the default and you will need to change `where` and `select` parts according to your need. I have used "Meeting" module for ilustration.

File path: custom\modules\\CustomMeeting.php

```
<?php

if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry)
    die('Not A Valid Entry Point');


require_once("modules/Meetings/Meeting.php");

class CustomMeeting extends Meeting
{

    /**
     * * constructor
     * */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::Meeting();
    }

    /**
     * Return the list query used by the list views and export button. Next generation of create_new_list_query function.
     *
     * Override this function to return a custom query.
     *
     * @param string $order_by custom order by clause
     * @param string $where custom where clause
     * @param array $filter Optioanal
     * @param array $params Optional     *
     * @param int $show_deleted Optional, default 0, show deleted records is set to 1.
     * @param string $join_type
     * @param boolean $return_array Optional, default false, response as array
     * @param object $parentbean creating a subquery for this bean.
     * @param boolean $singleSelect Optional, default false.
     * @return String select query string, optionally an array value will be returned if $return_array= true.
     */
    function create_new_list_query($order_by, $where, $filter = array(), $params = array(), $show_deleted = 0, $join_type = '', $return_array = false, $parentbean = null, $singleSelect = false, $ifListForExport = false)
    {
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal(print_r($_REQUEST, 1));
        global $beanFiles, $beanList;
        $selectedFields = array();
        $secondarySelectedFields = array();
        $ret_array = array();
        $distinct = '';
        if ($this->bean_implements('ACL') && ACLController::requireOwner($this->module_dir, 'list')) {
            global $current_user;
            $owner_where = $this->getOwnerWhere($current_user->id);
            if (empty($where)) {
                $where = $owner_where;
            } else {
                $where .= ' AND ' . $owner_where;
            }
        }
        /* BEGIN - SECURITY GROUPS */
        global $current_user, $sugar_config;
        if ($this->module_dir == 'Users' && !is_admin($current_user) && isset($sugar_config['securitysuite_filter_user_list']) && $sugar_config['securitysuite_filter_user_list'] == true
        ) {
            require_once('modules/SecurityGroups/SecurityGroup.php');
            global $current_user;
            $group_where = SecurityGroup::getGroupUsersWhere($current_user->id);
            //$group_where = "user_name = 'admin'";
            if (empty($where)) {
                $where = " (" . $group_where . ") ";
            } else {
                $where .= " AND (" . $group_where . ") ";
            }
        } else
        if ($this->bean_implements('ACL') && ACLController::requireSecurityGroup($this->module_dir, 'list')) {
            require_once('modules/SecurityGroups/SecurityGroup.php');
            global $current_user;
            $owner_where = $this->getOwnerWhere($current_user->id);
            $group_where = SecurityGroup::getGroupWhere($this->table_name, $this->module_dir, $current_user->id);
            if (!empty($owner_where)) {
                if (empty($where)) {
                    $where = " (" . $owner_where . " or " . $group_where . ") ";
                } else {
                    $where .= " AND (" . $owner_where . " or " . $group_where . ") ";
                }
            } else {
                $where .= ' AND ' . $group_where;
            }
        }
        /* END - SECURITY GROUPS */
        if (!empty($params['distinct'])) {
            $distinct = ' DISTINCT ';
        }
        if (empty($filter)) {
            $ret_array['select'] = " SELECT $distinct $this->table_name.* ";
        } else {
            $ret_array['select'] = " SELECT $distinct $this->table_name.id ";
        }
        $ret_array['from'] = " FROM $this->table_name ";
        $ret_array['from_min'] = $ret_array['from'];
        $ret_array['secondary_from'] = $ret_array['from'];
        $ret_array['where'] = '';
        $ret_array['order_by'] = '';
        //secondary selects are selects that need to be run after the primary query to retrieve additional info on main
        if ($singleSelect) {
            $ret_array['secondary_select'] = & $ret_array['select'];
            $ret_array['secondary_from'] = & $ret_array['from'];
        } else {
            $ret_array['secondary_select'] = '';
        }
        $custom_join = $this->getCustomJoin(empty($filter) ? true : $filter );
        if ((!isset($params['include_custom_fields']) || $params['include_custom_fields'])) {
            $ret_array['select'] .= $custom_join['select'];
        }
        $ret_array['from'] .= $custom_join['join'];
        // Bug 52490 - Captivea (Sve) - To be able to add custom fields inside where clause in a subpanel
        $ret_array['from_min'] .= $custom_join['join'];
        $jtcount = 0;
        //LOOP AROUND FOR FIXIN VARDEF ISSUES
        require('include/VarDefHandler/listvardefoverride.php');
        if (file_exists('custom/include/VarDefHandler/listvardefoverride.php')) {
            require('custom/include/VarDefHandler/listvardefoverride.php');
        }

        $joined_tables = array();
        if (!empty($params['joined_tables'])) {
            foreach ($params['joined_tables'] as $table) {
                $joined_tables[$table] = 1;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($filter)) {
            $filterKeys = array_keys($filter);
            if (is_numeric($filterKeys[0])) {
                $fields = array();
                foreach ($filter as $field) {
                    $field = strtolower($field);
                    //remove out id field so we don't duplicate it
                    if ($field == 'id' && !empty($filter)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (isset($this->field_defs[$field])) {
                        $fields[$field] = $this->field_defs[$field];
                    } else {
                        $fields[$field] = array('force_exists' => true);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $fields = $filter;
            }
        } else {
            $fields = $this->field_defs;
        }

        $used_join_key = array();

        //walk through the fields and for every relationship field add their relationship_info field
        //relationshipfield-aliases are resolved in SugarBean::create_new_list_query through their relationship_info field
        $addrelate = array();
        foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
            if (isset($this->field_defs[$field]) && isset($this->field_defs[$field]['source']) &&
                $this->field_defs[$field]['source'] == 'non-db') {
                $addrelatefield = $this->get_relationship_field($field);
                if ($addrelatefield)
                    $addrelate[$addrelatefield] = true;
            }
            if (!empty($this->field_defs[$field]['id_name'])) {
                $addrelate[$this->field_defs[$field]['id_name']] = true;
            }
        }

        $fields = array_merge($addrelate, $fields);

        foreach ($fields as $field => $value) {
            //alias is used to alias field names
            $alias = '';
            if (isset($value['alias'])) {
                $alias = ' as ' . $value['alias'] . ' ';
            }

            if (empty($this->field_defs[$field]) || !empty($value['force_blank'])) {
                if (!empty($filter) && isset($filter[$field]['force_exists']) && $filter[$field]['force_exists']) {
                    if (isset($filter[$field]['force_default']))
                        $ret_array['select'] .= ", {$filter[$field]['force_default']} $field ";
                    else
                    //spaces are a fix for length issue problem with unions.  The union only returns the maximum number of characters from the first select statement.
                        $ret_array['select'] .= ", '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ' $field ";
                }
                continue;
            }
            else {
                $data = $this->field_defs[$field];
            }

            //ignore fields that are a part of the collection and a field has been removed as a result of
            //layout customization.. this happens in subpanel customizations, use case, from the contacts subpanel
            //in opportunities module remove the contact_role/opportunity_role field.
            if (isset($data['relationship_fields']) and ! empty($data['relationship_fields'])) {
                $process_field = false;
                foreach ($data['relationship_fields'] as $field_name) {
                    if (isset($fields[$field_name])) {
                        $process_field = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!$process_field)
                    continue;
            }

            if ((!isset($data['source']) || $data['source'] == 'db') && (!empty($alias) || !empty($filter) )) {
                $ret_array['select'] .= ", $this->table_name.$field $alias";
                $selectedFields["$this->table_name.$field"] = true;
            } else if ((!isset($data['source']) || $data['source'] == 'custom_fields') && (!empty($alias) || !empty($filter) )) {
                //add this column only if it has NOT already been added to select statement string
                $colPos = strpos($ret_array['select'], "$this->table_name" . "_cstm" . ".$field");
                if (!$colPos || $colPos < 0) {
                    $ret_array['select'] .= ", $this->table_name" . "_cstm" . ".$field $alias";
                }

                $selectedFields["$this->table_name.$field"] = true;
            }

            if ($data['type'] != 'relate' && isset($data['db_concat_fields'])) {
                $ret_array['select'] .= ", " . $this->db->concat($this->table_name, $data['db_concat_fields']) . " as $field";
                $selectedFields[$this->db->concat($this->table_name, $data['db_concat_fields'])] = true;
            }
            //Custom relate field or relate fields built in module builder which have no link field associated.
            if ($data['type'] == 'relate' && (isset($data['custom_module']) || isset($data['ext2']))) {
                $joinTableAlias = 'jt' . $jtcount;
                $relateJoinInfo = $this->custom_fields->getRelateJoin($data, $joinTableAlias, false);
                $ret_array['select'] .= $relateJoinInfo['select'];
                $ret_array['from'] .= $relateJoinInfo['from'];
                //Replace any references to the relationship in the where clause with the new alias
                //If the link isn't set, assume that search used the local table for the field
                $searchTable = isset($data['link']) ? $relateJoinInfo['rel_table'] : $this->table_name;
                $field_name = $relateJoinInfo['rel_table'] . '.' . !empty($data['name']) ? $data['name'] : 'name';
                $where = preg_replace('/(^|[\s(])' . $field_name . '/', '${1}' . $relateJoinInfo['name_field'], $where);
                $jtcount++;
            }
            //Parent Field
            if ($data['type'] == 'parent') {
                //See if we need to join anything by inspecting the where clause
                $match = preg_match('/(^|[\s(])parent_(\w+)_(\w+)\.name/', $where, $matches);
                if ($match) {
                    $joinTableAlias = 'jt' . $jtcount;
                    $joinModule = $matches[2];
                    $joinTable = $matches[3];
                    $localTable = $this->table_name;
                    if (!empty($data['custom_module'])) {
                        $localTable .= '_cstm';
                    }
                    global $beanFiles, $beanList, $module;
                    require_once($beanFiles[$beanList[$joinModule]]);
                    $rel_mod = new $beanList[$joinModule]();
                    $nameField = "$joinTableAlias.name";
                    if (isset($rel_mod->field_defs['name'])) {
                        $name_field_def = $rel_mod->field_defs['name'];
                        if (isset($name_field_def['db_concat_fields'])) {
                            $nameField = $this->db->concat($joinTableAlias, $name_field_def['db_concat_fields']);
                        }
                    }
                    $ret_array['select'] .= ", $nameField {$data['name']} ";
                    $ret_array['from'] .= " LEFT JOIN $joinTable $joinTableAlias
                        ON $localTable.{$data['id_name']} = $joinTableAlias.id";
                    //Replace any references to the relationship in the where clause with the new alias
                    $where = preg_replace('/(^|[\s(])parent_' . $joinModule . '_' . $joinTable . '\.name/', '${1}' . $nameField, $where);
                    $jtcount++;
                }
            }

            if ($this->is_relate_field($field)) {
                $this->load_relationship($data['link']);
                if (!empty($this->$data['link'])) {
                    $params = array();
                    if (empty($join_type)) {
                        $params['join_type'] = ' LEFT JOIN ';
                    } else {
                        $params['join_type'] = $join_type;
                    }
                    if (isset($data['join_name'])) {
                        $params['join_table_alias'] = $data['join_name'];
                    } else {
                        $params['join_table_alias'] = 'jt' . $jtcount;
                    }
                    if (isset($data['join_link_name'])) {
                        $params['join_table_link_alias'] = $data['join_link_name'];
                    } else {
                        $params['join_table_link_alias'] = 'jtl' . $jtcount;
                    }
                    $join_primary = !isset($data['join_primary']) || $data['join_primary'];

                    $join = $this->$data['link']->getJoin($params, true);
                    $used_join_key[] = $join['rel_key'];
                    $rel_module = $this->$data['link']->getRelatedModuleName();
                    $table_joined = !empty($joined_tables[$params['join_table_alias']]) || (!empty($joined_tables[$params['join_table_link_alias']]) && isset($data['link_type']) && $data['link_type'] == 'relationship_info');

                    //if rname is set to 'name', and bean files exist, then check if field should be a concatenated name
                    global $beanFiles, $beanList;
                    // °3/21/2014 FIX NS-TEAM - Relationship fields could not be displayed in subpanels
                    //if($data['rname'] && !empty($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]])) {
                    if (isset($data['rname']) && $data['rname'] == 'name' && !empty($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]])) {

                        //create an instance of the related bean
                        require_once($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]]);
                        $rel_mod = new $beanList[$rel_module]();
                        //if bean has first and last name fields, then name should be concatenated
                        if (isset($rel_mod->field_name_map['first_name']) && isset($rel_mod->field_name_map['last_name'])) {
                            $data['db_concat_fields'] = array(0 => 'first_name', 1 => 'last_name');
                        }
                    }


                    if ($join['type'] == 'many-to-many') {
                        if (empty($ret_array['secondary_select'])) {
                            $ret_array['secondary_select'] = " SELECT $this->table_name.id ref_id  ";

                            if (!empty($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]]) && $join_primary) {
                                require_once($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]]);
                                $rel_mod = new $beanList[$rel_module]();
                                if (isset($rel_mod->field_defs['assigned_user_id'])) {
                                    $ret_array['secondary_select'].= " , " . $params['join_table_alias'] . ".assigned_user_id {$field}_owner, '$rel_module' {$field}_mod";
                                } else {
                                    if (isset($rel_mod->field_defs['created_by'])) {
                                        $ret_array['secondary_select'].= " , " . $params['join_table_alias'] . ".created_by {$field}_owner , '$rel_module' {$field}_mod";
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        if (isset($data['db_concat_fields'])) {
                            $ret_array['secondary_select'] .= ' , ' . $this->db->concat($params['join_table_alias'], $data['db_concat_fields']) . ' ' . $field;
                        } else {
                            if (!isset($data['relationship_fields'])) {
                                $ret_array['secondary_select'] .= ' , ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.' . $data['rname'] . ' ' . $field;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!$singleSelect) {
                            $ret_array['select'] .= ", '                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ' $field ";
                        }
                        $count_used = 0;
                        foreach ($used_join_key as $used_key) {
                            if ($used_key == $join['rel_key'])
                                $count_used++;
                        }
                        if ($count_used <= 1) {//27416, the $ret_array['secondary_select'] should always generate, regardless the dbtype
                            // add rel_key only if it was not aready added
                            if (!$singleSelect) {
                                $ret_array['select'] .= ", '                                    '  " . $join['rel_key'] . ' ';
                            }
                            $ret_array['secondary_select'] .= ', ' . $params['join_table_link_alias'] . '.' . $join['rel_key'] . ' ' . $join['rel_key'];
                        }
                        if (isset($data['relationship_fields'])) {
                            foreach ($data['relationship_fields'] as $r_name => $alias_name) {
                                if (!empty($secondarySelectedFields[$alias_name]))
                                    continue;
                                $ret_array['secondary_select'] .= ', ' . $params['join_table_link_alias'] . '.' . $r_name . ' ' . $alias_name;
                                $secondarySelectedFields[$alias_name] = true;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!$table_joined) {
                            $ret_array['secondary_from'] .= ' ' . $join['join'] . ' AND ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.deleted=0';
                            if (isset($data['link_type']) && $data['link_type'] == 'relationship_info' && ($parentbean instanceOf SugarBean)) {
                                $ret_array['secondary_where'] = $params['join_table_link_alias'] . '.' . $join['rel_key'] . "='" . $parentbean->id . "'";
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (isset($data['db_concat_fields'])) {
                            $ret_array['select'] .= ' , ' . $this->db->concat($params['join_table_alias'], $data['db_concat_fields']) . ' ' . $field;
                        } else {
                            $ret_array['select'] .= ' , ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.' . $data['rname'] . ' ' . $field;
                        }
                        if (isset($data['additionalFields'])) {
                            foreach ($data['additionalFields'] as $k => $v) {
                                if (!empty($data['id_name']) && $data['id_name'] == $v && !empty($fields[$data['id_name']])) {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                $ret_array['select'] .= ' , ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.' . $k . ' ' . $v;
                            }
                        }
                        if (!$table_joined) {
                            $ret_array['from'] .= ' ' . $join['join'] . ' AND ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.deleted=0';
                            if (!empty($beanList[$rel_module]) && !empty($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]])) {
                                require_once($beanFiles[$beanList[$rel_module]]);
                                $rel_mod = new $beanList[$rel_module]();
                                if (isset($value['target_record_key']) && !empty($filter)) {
                                    $selectedFields[$this->table_name . '.' . $value['target_record_key']] = true;
                                    $ret_array['select'] .= " , $this->table_name.{$value['target_record_key']} ";
                                }
                                if (isset($rel_mod->field_defs['assigned_user_id'])) {
                                    $ret_array['select'] .= ' , ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.assigned_user_id ' . $field . '_owner';
                                } else {
                                    $ret_array['select'] .= ' , ' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.created_by ' . $field . '_owner';
                                }
                                $ret_array['select'] .= "  , '" . $rel_module . "' " . $field . '_mod';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    // To fix SOAP stuff where we are trying to retrieve all the accounts data where accounts.id = ..
                    // and this code changes accounts to jt4 as there is a self join with the accounts table.
                    //Martin fix #27494
                    if (isset($data['db_concat_fields'])) {
                        $buildWhere = false;
                        if (in_array('first_name', $data['db_concat_fields']) && in_array('last_name', $data['db_concat_fields'])) {
                            $exp = '/\(\s*?' . $data['name'] . '.*?\%\'\s*?\)/';
                            if (preg_match($exp, $where, $matches)) {
                                $search_expression = $matches[0];
                                //Create three search conditions - first + last, first, last
                                $first_name_search = str_replace($data['name'], $params['join_table_alias'] . '.first_name', $search_expression);
                                $last_name_search = str_replace($data['name'], $params['join_table_alias'] . '.last_name', $search_expression);
                                $full_name_search = str_replace($data['name'], $this->db->concat($params['join_table_alias'], $data['db_concat_fields']), $search_expression);
                                $buildWhere = true;
                                $where = str_replace($search_expression, '(' . $full_name_search . ' OR ' . $first_name_search . ' OR ' . $last_name_search . ')', $where);
                            }
                        }

                        if (!$buildWhere) {
                            $db_field = $this->db->concat($params['join_table_alias'], $data['db_concat_fields']);
                            $where = preg_replace('/' . $data['name'] . '/', $db_field, $where);

                            // For relationship fields replace their alias by the corresponsding link table and r_name
                            if (isset($data['relationship_fields']))
                                foreach ($data['relationship_fields'] as $r_name => $alias_name) {
                                    $db_field = $this->db->concat($params['join_table_link_alias'], $r_name);
                                    $where = preg_replace('/' . $alias_name . '/', $db_field, $where);
                                }
                        }
                    } else {
                        $where = preg_replace('/(^|[\s(])' . $data['name'] . '/', '${1}' . $params['join_table_alias'] . '.' . $data['rname'], $where);

                        // For relationship fields replace their alias by the corresponsding link table and r_name
                        if (isset($data['relationship_fields']))
                            foreach ($data['relationship_fields'] as $r_name => $alias_name)
                                $where = preg_replace('/(^|[\s(])' . $alias_name . '/', '${1}' . $params['join_table_link_alias'] . '.' . $r_name, $where);
                    }
                    if (!$table_joined) {
                        $joined_tables[$params['join_table_alias']] = 1;
                        $joined_tables[$params['join_table_link_alias']] = 1;
                    }

                    $jtcount++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!empty($filter)) {
            if (isset($this->field_defs['assigned_user_id']) && empty($selectedFields[$this->table_name . '.assigned_user_id'])) {
                $ret_array['select'] .= ", $this->table_name.assigned_user_id ";
            } else if (isset($this->field_defs['created_by']) && empty($selectedFields[$this->table_name . '.created_by'])) {
                $ret_array['select'] .= ", $this->table_name.created_by ";
            }
            if (isset($this->field_defs['system_id']) && empty($selectedFields[$this->table_name . '.system_id'])) {
                $ret_array['select'] .= ", $this->table_name.system_id ";
            }
        }    
        $where_auto = '1=1';
        if ($show_deleted == 0) {
            $where_auto = "$this->table_name.deleted=0";
        } else if ($show_deleted == 1) {
            $where_auto = "$this->table_name.deleted=1";
        }
        if ($where != "")
            $ret_array['where'] = " where ($where) AND $where_auto";
        else
            $ret_array['where'] = " where $where_auto";

        //make call to process the order by clause
        $order_by = $this->process_order_by($order_by);
        if (!empty($order_by)) {
            $ret_array['order_by'] = " ORDER BY " . $order_by;
        }
        if ($singleSelect) {
            unset($ret_array['secondary_where']);
            unset($ret_array['secondary_from']);
            unset($ret_array['secondary_select']);
        }    

        if (<your check goes here>) {                
            $ret_array['from'] = $ret_array['from'] . " your sql to fetch data ";
     $ret_array['where'] .=" AND meetings.id NOT IN (some condition)";
        }

        if ($return_array) {
            return $ret_array;
        }

        return $ret_array['select'] . $ret_array['from'] . $ret_array['where'] . $ret_array['order_by'];
    }

}
```